# Problems with ActiveRecord after certain amount of columns in table

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I first had this problem like a week ago and I guess the fact wasn't very well explained mainly because I couldn't isolate the problem...apparently now I have...but still don't know its nature

I have a migration that goes like:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up   
    create_table :users do |t|      
        t.references "faculty"
         t.references "department"
         t.references "role", :null => false
        t.string "name", :null => false, :limit => 20
         t.string "surname", :null => false, :limit => 20
        t.string "username",:null => false, :limit => 25
        t.string "study_group",:limit => 6
        t.string "study_course",:limit => 50
        t.string "card_code",:limit => 12
        t.boolean "During_Day",:default => false
        t.string "email", :limit => 100 
        t.string "hashed_password", :limit => 40            
        t.string "salt", :limit => 40           
    end     
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

If I start to create users from the rails console and save them when trying to recover the data through

```
  User.all
```

some fields' info would be corrupted.I started to remove fields and it works when I leave the first 8 columns (including the ID which is created by default).Creating a ninth column or even more would damage everything and afterwards I'm getting all kind of not correct information in my views.
I must say that when from the rails console I save something and then check it from the mysql command line then the info is fine....so what's ActiveRecord missing?

output for:

> Could you run `show create table users\G` from mysql console?

```
  mysql> show create table users\G
  *************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: users
  Create Table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `faculty_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `study_group` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `study_course` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `card_code` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `day_time` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `email` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `hashed_password` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `salt` varchar(40) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `faculty` (`faculty_id`),
  KEY `department` (`department_id`),
  KEY `role` (`role_id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 1 row in set (0.02 sec)
 mysql>
```

adding user from the rails console

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> me = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, faculty_id: nil, department_id: nil, role_id: nil,
name: "", surname: "", username: "", study_group: nil, study_cour
se: nil, card_code: nil, day_time: false, email: nil, hashed_password:
nil, salt: nil>
irb(main):002:0> me.name = 'Daniel'
=> "Daniel"
irb(main):003:0> me.surname = 'Garcia'
=> "Garcia"
irb(main):004:0> me.username = 'vinagrito'
=> "vinagrito"
irb(main):005:0> me.role_id = 1
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> me.save
=> false
irb(main):007:0> me.errors
=> {:password=>["is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"], :email=>["is
invalid", "can't be blank"]}
irb(main):008:0> me.password = '12345678'
=> "12345678"
irb(main):009:0> me.email = 'mail@mail.com'
=> "mail@mail.com"
irb(main):010:0> me.save
=> true
irb(main):011:0> me
=> #<User id: 2, faculty_id: nil, department_id: nil, role_id: 1, name:
"Daniel", surname: "Garcia", username: "vinagrito", study_group
: nil, study_course: nil, card_code: nil, day_time: false, email:
"mail@mail.com", hashed_password: "6305ee7016b263c0ec41a81439a378837a
318035", salt: "5c33e8fed10b87c9f4b7841f0faeb7b10424289a">   
irb(main):013:0> user = User.where(:id => 2)
=> [#<User id: 2, faculty_id: nil, department_id: nil, role_id: 1, name:
"Daniel", surname: "Garcia", username: "vinagrito", study_grou
p: nil, study_course: nil, card_code: nil, day_time: false, email:
"mail@mail.com", hashed_password: 6305.0, salt: "5c33e8fed10b87c9f4b
7841f0faeb7b10424289a">]
```

See the "hashed_password" it returns to me

Output of the development.log

```
 [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSHOW TABLES[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  SHOW TABLES
 [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM
 `schema_migrations`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (31.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT
 NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `faculty_id` int(11), `department_id`
 int(11), `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `study_group` varchar(6), `study_course` varchar(50), `card_code`
 varchar(15), `day_time` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0, `email` varchar(100),
 `hashed_password` varchar(40), `salt` varchar(40)) ENGINE=InnoDB
 [1m[36mSQL (68.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE INDEX faculty ON
  users(faculty_id)[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (65.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX department ON
 users(department_id)
 [1m[36mSQL (78.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE INDEX role ON users(role_id)[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (80.8ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX username ON users(username)
 [1m[36mSQL (30.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (`version`)
 VALUES ('20101226144503')[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  SHOW TABLES
 [1m[36mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM
 `schema_migrations`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  SHOW TABLES
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `authors`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `authors`
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `book_loans`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `book_loans`
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `books`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `books`
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `departments`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `departments`
 [1m[36mSQL (8.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `faculties`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `faculties`
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `roles`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `roles`
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `subjects`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `subjects`
 [1m[36mSQL (7.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `users`[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  SHOW KEYS FROM `users`
 [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSHOW TABLES[0m
 [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
 [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mdescribe `users`[0m
 [1m[35mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `users` (`faculty_id`,
 `department_id`, `role_id`, `name`, `surname`, `username`,
 `study_group`, `study_course`, `card_code`, `day_time`, `email`,
 `hashed_password`, `salt`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 1, 'Daniel', 'Garcia',
 'viangrito', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 'mail@mail.com',
 'e1382ac8675daee167a262ee7ef3bd038f997c4a',
 'a3518e0a6b273590073bd733e2ee692fbca28c2d')
 [1m[36mSQL (15.6ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

Comment: Not sure but isn't the syntax supposed to be `t.string :username, :null => false [, ...]` using a symbol instead of a string? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration Might not be related to this problem, just a side note...

Comment: I've tried this too.On one machine I have t.string "username",.... on the other t.string :username,...  same effects.It's frustrating

Comment: @Daniel: Is this Rails 3? New app or converted from old Rails version? Are you using mysql2 gem?

Comment: Brand new app on rails 3 and I'm using the mysql2 gem

Comment: @Daniel: Interesting.. :) Could you run `show create table users\G` from mysql console? Are there any less known plugins or gems in use?

Comment: @Daniel: Are the steps in question description enough to reproduce the problem? If so, how the corrupt info shows up after repeating the steps?

Comment: @Daniel: Have you monkey patched any existing Ruby/Rails classes? Have done something that deviates a lot from the normal Rails conventions?

Comment: @Heikki 1.>could you run show create tableusers\G...Seems to give the correct schema for my table 2.Yeah their are.I mean I have the hashing method inside my model a validations for some of the values above.I removed the hashing method and left just two validations...the problem doesn't go...next step:no validations at all 3.I have to say I don't know what is a monkey patch.I suppose I've keep on Rails conventions

Comment: @Daniel. I am asking to actually see that output :)

Comment: @Daniel: Steps to reproduce something would be like: create a new app, run this migration, run this command from the console and then this problem should show up.

Comment: @Daniel: You can use (for example) https://gist.github.com/ to add more info if you don't want to include it in your question.

Comment: @Heikki steps: 1.created DB books_library_development 2.created app: rails new books_library -d mysql 3.created model:rails generate model Book 3.(when migration ready) rake db:migration (also tried specifying version rake db:migration:up version=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) 4.launched rails console and created an instance of my User and filled some of the fields 5.saved (successfully) 6.When querying User.all field "hashed_password" corrupted (I'll add some info inside the question)

Comment: it treats the field "hashed_password" as an integer

Comment: Hmm.. weird. And you have tried those steps with fresh app and database? I might test this later this week.

Comment: Yeah...when it all started to go wrong on my PC I went to my laptop and started all over.Only there I have to say I removed the hashing method and some of the validations...but it didn't work either.I guess I could try on a third machine.That so far has never seen a line of code in its life

Comment: Why do you need a new machine to repeat those steps? App and database names don't need to be identical. Just remember to repeat only the steps you listed. Don't do or copy any additional stuff from the old app.

Comment: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/71  I was just there.This might be the answer.As soon as I try it I'll post back.Til tomorrow!

Comment: Yes, that would expain it quite well. Write an anwer to your question if you solve it. It helps the next person to track down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after a couple of days of struggling, yesterday I found

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/71

Which was found trying to locate someone else with similar problems
I don't know how it was for other windows users but my schema.rb was showing me no schema at all just:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) do #my last migration version

     #Could not dump table "table_name" beacuse of following ArgumentError
     #     invalid date
     .
     .
     .# and so one for each table I had
   end
```

So I downloaded mysql 5.1. from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html and now everything's working like it should.
Not it shows the full schema of my db and when retrieving data from it no longer gets corrupted